# instantiate object with reflection using constructor

Tags: c#

I'm creating an instance of a class object using reflection and calling a method within that class:

```
    // Get ExportLines type
    Type type = typeof(ExportLines);

    // Create an instance of ExportLines type
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    // Retrieve the variable method name from ExportLines
    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("ExportLine_" + ExportLineNumber.ToString());

    // Invoke the method on the instance created above with _Data object parameter
    var val = methodInfo.Invoke(obj, new object[] { _Data, dataStrings});

    //Add to txt file (later)
    return val.ToString();
```

As you can see at the moment I'm invoking the method with a couple of parameters, what i actually want to do is initialise the class and with those parameters and set a global variable for use in all methods during that class instance.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: You want to set a variable on the created instance that can be used on all methods that belong to that instance? Where is the problem? Create a public property for the class to be created and set its value after you built the instance.

Comment: I can't have anything in the actual methods 'ExportLine_x' that are being called that sets the global variable, it needs to be a constructor for the class, i just can't quite see how to initialise the type with parameters in reflection, any examples might help. Thanks :)

Comment: You could use properties on the type? If you implement an interface, you don't need reflection to assign the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you should add a constructor to the `ExportLines` class accepting `_Data` and `dataStrings` as parameters. This constructor should make sure it saves the passed parameters for later use, inside the `ExportLine_n` method. Now you can use the [`Activator.CreateInstance Method (Type, Object\[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx) overload which creates an instance of the specified type using the constructor that best matches the specified parameters.

Comment: Ok so if i understand correctly the Activator.CreateInstance(type) function can also take a second parameter which holds an object with the parameters, this will apply to the default constructor of the class 'type'?

Comment: Yes: `creates an instance of the specified type using the constructor that best matches the specified parameters.` So if you for example use: Activator.CreateInstance(type, { string, string}) it will look for a constructor accepting two strings as parameters.

Comment: @DanHall An array of objects that will hold the arguments.

Comment: That's great, i should really read the documentation :) cheers!